# Tensorflow: creating a serving input function that reads from sparse values

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-transform

I'm creating an estimator in Tensorflow using preprocessed data from tf.Transform. For serving time, I want to be able to read directly from a JSON file like the one below:

```
{"uid":"123","item_ids":["23","f4","6g"],"top_k":5}
```

The `top_k` value is not part of the model graph and is used inside the estimator only on serving time. My problem is that I don't know to represent the value `item_ids` which is a sparse tensor.

My serving function is the following:

```
def serving_input_fn():
    inputs = {}
    for key, t in zip(metadata.SERVING_CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS, metadata.SERVING_CATEGORICAL_DEFAULTS):
        # here should read the list values as sparse placeholders but 
        # sparse_placeholder produces a SparseTensor which
        # produce the error ValueError: receiver_tensor item_ids must be a Tensor.
        # in ServingInputReceiver
        if isinstance(t, list):
            inputs.update({key:tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string)}) 
        else:
            inputs.update({key:tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string)})

    for key, t in zip(metadata.SERVING_NUMERICAL_COLUMNS, metadata.SERVING_NUMERICAL_DEFAULTS):
        if isinstance(t, list):
            inputs.update({key:tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.float32)})
        else:
            inputs.update({key:tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.float32)})

    features = {}
    for key, tensor in inputs.items():
        if isinstance(tensor, tf.SparseTensor):
            features[key] = tensor
        else:
            features[key] = tf.expand_dims(tensor, -1)

    # here because the top_k value was not part of the preprocessing using
    # tf.Transform I pass only the values that need preprocessing
    raw_features_to_transform = {k: features[k] for k in metadata.INPUT_FEATURE_NAMES}
    transformed_features = tf_transform_output.transform_raw_features(
        raw_features_to_transform)
    transformed_features = {k: transformed_features[k] for k in metadata.SERVING_COLUMNS if k in transformed_features}
    features.update(transformed_features)

    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(
        features=features,
        receiver_tensors=inputs
    )
```

When I am running the above-generated graph with `gcloud ml-engine local predict` I get the following error

```
prediction.prediction_lib.PredictionError: Failed to run the provided model: 
Exception during running the graph: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 3) 
for Tensor u'Placeholder_1:0', which has shape '(?,)' (Error code: 2)
```

where `Placeholder_1:0` is the placeholder for the `item_ids` values.

Any ideas on how to support variable length values?

Answer (score 0):

There's likely an issue with the way the placeholders are defined.
Please take a look at this example:
https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/blob/v0.8.0/examples/sentiment_example.py#L271

Our example is using a parsing serving input function which uses a feature spec.
It's getting the feature spec from the raw metadata, but in your case since you're not parsing the input data you could just do something similar and call:

```
RAW_DATA_METADATA.schema.as_batched_placeholders()
```

Which defines the placeholders for you.

Comment: The fact that I can get the placeholders like this is very handy but sadly it doesn't solve my problem since for the item_ids input it produces a SparseTensor (which is desirable in order to pass this input into the tf.Transform graph) but tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver raises the following error: ValueError: receiver_tensor item_ids must be a Tensor.

Comment: Yes, look like ServingInputReceiver doesn't support SparseTensor receiver_tensors before TF 1.9.


Could you upgrade TF to 1.9 and try again?


(Even though this configuration is not officially supported -- have tf.Transform 0.8, TF 1.9).

Comment: @Zohar Did you find a solution? I'm having the exact same problem and being asking to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `tf.placeholder(shape=[None], ...)` creates a placeholder with its shape being a vector of unknown length. You probably want to specify `tf.placeholder(shape=None, ...)` to specify a fully unknown shape (which might be a matrix, which is what you're passing at serving time) when you create your placeholders.